# How to Stop jQuery from Buffering Hover Effects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two images stacked on top of each other and trying to use it for navigation. On hover I am using jQuery to fadeTo 0 and back to 1 when cursor leaves. This is working but here is my problem. If you run the mouse cursor over the list item back and forth a few times, it is buffer the effects. How do I stop it from buffer? Thanks!

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("li").hover(function(){
$(this).fadeTo(250, 0);
},function(){
$(this).fadeTo(350, 1);
});
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="link1img"></div>

  <ul>
  <li id="link1"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
```

CSS

```
#link1 {
background-image: url(../images/home_normal.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-indent: -9999px;
position: absolute;
height: 17px;
width: 67px;
left: 0px;
top: 10px;
}
#link1img {
background-image: url(../images/home_mo.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
height: 17px;
width: 67px;
left: 0px;
top: 11px;
}
```

Comment: jQuery does not buffer. What you are referring to is the animation queue. In addition to the .stop() method which clears the queue (as mentioned in the answers below). There is also .dequeue() which will not clear the queue, but put that animation first in line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop the old effects using [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) before continuing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(250, 0);
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo(350, 1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.stop(true)` to cancel any animations currently in progress on that object and remove them from the animation queue so your next animation can start immediately and not have to wait until the current one finishes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").hover(function(){
        $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(250, 0);
    },function(){
        $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(350, 1);
    });
});
```

See the [jQuery reference on `.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) for more info.